# Get other table column value in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i have below query

```
Deal::with(array('deal_category'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('name as dealcategory');
                }))->get()
```

when i try to retrieve `dealcategory` it does not return any value. I have defined relationship in model like

Deal Model

```
public function deal_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DealCategory', 'deal_category_id', 'id');
}
```

And Deal category model like

```
public function deals(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Deal','deal_category_id');
}
```

can anyone help how can i get categoryname?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the primary key to retrieve the necessary results.

```
Deal::with(array('deal_category'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id', 'name as dealcategory');
            }))->get()
```

Comment: After getting records how can i display record from relationship array?

Comment: `$deal->deal_category->dealcategory` I think it would be better if you keep 'name' to do something like  `$deal->deal_category->name`.

Answer (score -2):

Use facade `DB`.
You can try something like this:

```
    DB::table('deal as d')
    ->join('deal_category as dc', 'd.id', '=', 'dc.deal_id')
    ->select('d.name as dealname', 'dc.categoryname')
    ->get();
```